# Is it safe to clean out a computer with air compressor?

Tags: hardware

I need to clean my desktop, it is full of dust. Is it safe to use a compressor to clean it? I mean, can I have problem with static, water, dirty, moisture or other stuff been blown on the hardware?

Comment: This is off topic for Electronic Design, but you can use an air compressor ***if*** you ensure it is free of moisture in the line and use ~40psi or less.

Comment: There could be a **bit** of moisture if the computer is not on and you absorb any obvious wet spots and let it dry. Look, I put a Dell keyboard into a dishwasher (without dissassembling it) and it was fine. (I don't recommend this: drying it is time consuming; it's less of a hassle to disassemble it and avoid washing the circuit boards and membranes.) But the point is, the device survived. I'm using it as we speak.

Comment: I've been cleaning my computers and laptop with compressed air for years. Haven't had any issues yet.

Comment: When I entered your title as a new question the first related question that popped up was "Cleaning Circuits with Compressed Air". Please read previous post before asking the same thing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice. Don't use a compressor. While it is possible to create the conditions where it's safe to use, more often than not, static generated as the air passes through the line, dirt and moisture can all be problems. It can also jam dust further in rather than removing it.

If your computer needs a clean, use a brush (one like [this](http://www.pccasegear.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=13685&cPath=266&utm_source=googlebase&utm_medium=cse&utm_campaign=export_feed&gclid=CPnClYn9jLkCFcYipQodTSoADQ#googlebase) will be ESD safe, if you use a regular brush, keep it away from electronics) and a vacuum cleaner. Saved cleaning up the dust afterwards. Filters and heat sinks that can be removed from the system can be hit with the air. Just discharge them when you're done.

Comment: Using a brush could be a bad idea as static voltages may be built up by just brushing. At least keep the brush away from the electronics.

Comment: Good point. I failed to mention that. Will update now.

Comment: so, what can I use to cleanup the electronics? Like the motherboard, GPU?

Comment: Use an ESD safe brush if you want to clean components. While it may seem trivial, you don't want to spend all the time cleaning the board only to find that it doesn't work because you damaged a chip. The brushes are pretty cheap and can be bought from pretty much any tech store. Most dust will build up on the top side of horizontally orientated boards and wherever there is a fan. Most GPU and CPU heat sinks can be removed to clean. Just be careful of the thermal paste.